# Getting wrong coordinate system with $y function

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, geometry, qgis-processing

I have a shapefile that I need to add Lat Lon attributes to attribute table. I am using the `$y` but the number I get is not from the correct coordinate system I want. I have changed the coordinate system of shapefile in properties to the one I need (EPSG:4326 - WGS 84) and when I use the `$y` I'm still getting the old coordinate system number (EPSG:3735 - NAD83 / Ohio South (ftUS)

Comment: Use the answer under the similar question: `y(transform($geometry, @layer_crs, 'EPSG:4326'))`

Comment: And never change the coordinate system in the layer property !